# Как получить дату начала и конца по selection в ChartArea

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, диаграммы

Есть чарт с мультисерией. Ось Х - тип datetime. 
Пытаюсь при выделение области оси получить дату начала выделения и конца, но не получается.
Вот как пытался делать:

```
private void chart9_CursorPositionChanging(object sender, CursorEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!double.IsNaN(e.ChartArea.CursorX.SelectionStart) && !double.IsNaN(e.ChartArea.CursorX.SelectionEnd))
            {
                StartDateTime = DateTime.FromOADate(e.ChartArea.AxisX.PositionToValue(e.ChartArea.CursorX.SelectionStart));
                EndDateTime = DateTime.FromOADate(e.ChartArea.AxisX.PositionToValue(e.ChartArea.CursorX.SelectionEnd));
            }
        }
```

Но получаю неверную дату. Помогите с решением

Answer (score 0):

Пока сделал так

```
private void chart9_CursorPositionChanging(object sender, CursorEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!double.IsNaN(e.ChartArea.CursorX.SelectionStart) && !double.IsNaN(e.ChartArea.CursorX.SelectionEnd))
            {
                StartDateTime = DateTime.FromOADate(chart9.Series[0].Points[(int)e.ChartArea.CursorX.SelectionStart-1].XValue);
                EndDateTime = DateTime.FromOADate(chart9.Series[0].Points[(int)e.ChartArea.CursorX.SelectionEnd-2].XValue);
            }
        }
```